# iphone app websites - the iphone frame

Tags: iphone, web

Hy folks, i have a "where to find" & "what rules" question this time rather then specific coding, so please exuse me if it is the wrong place, but i have just so much trust in stackO that i don't know where to look for after bad googling.

I'm doing a site for an iphone app, and in 99% all these sites have an iphone screenshot of their application, well, i need that iphone frame so that i can put a slideshow of the UI inside.

Are there any strict rules or a place where i can get such a frame or can i just take one from someones iphone app website?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a great one from Apple. Go to the iOS Dev Center and log in. Then click on "Marketing Resources" under "App Store Resources" on the right. Then get the ["App Store Badging and Artwork"](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/AppStoreMarketingGuidelines.pdf). You have to agree to their terms of use and send back a signed form, but you get access to the "official" images for all the latest hardware right away, along with the little "Available on the App Store" graphics.

These give you the frames, then you can crop the screenshots inside. It looks better than taking a screenshot of the simulator showing the App (which you can also do, using cmd-shift-4).

Comment: thx very much, unfortunately it is sunday and the guy i do this for does not pick up his phone on weekends, and i need to show some results tommorow, so either i do a temp solution by just DL from someones approved site or i wait with that part, anyway i can't see the link you gave i don't have an apple ID. thx anyway

Comment: is it possible/legit that you or someone else mail the graphic to me? I just don't see why apple can't give that public available

Comment: Details of what you get are [here](http://developer.apple.com/appstore/AppStoreMarketingGuidelines.pdf). If you do not have an Apple ID, then you cannot get access, so try running the app in the simulator and using cmd-shift-4 to take a screenshot of the simulator running your app.

Comment: @Johua: If I did that, I would be violating the terms of use, so I cannot help you there. Sorry.

Comment: ok i get it, yes but these scr.shots don't have the cool glossy and shadows..but that's ok i will just have to get that devID tommorow and login to see for myself..